# Teloxide-rs How to share state between different instances of the same bot?

Tags: rust, persistence, telegram-bot

I'm using [teloxide](https://docs.rs/teloxide) a bot that coordinates information between players of a game. As a simplified example, I want player A to mark task_1 as complete, and then I want player B to be able to ask the bot if task_1 has been completed or not and for the bot to respond appropriately.

So far I've tried the [in-memory](https://docs.rs/teloxide/latest/teloxide/dispatching/dialogue/struct.InMemStorage.html) storage and the [Redis](https://docs.rs/teloxide/latest/teloxide/dispatching/dialogue/struct.RedisStorage.html) storage, and both seem to be storing independent states. For example Player A can mark a task as complete, but when player B asks about the state of that task, it remains incomplete.

I haven't got sqlite setup on my machine so haven't tried it yet, but I wouldn't imagine it's setup differently to redis(?).

I could theoretically write the bot's state to a file on disk and then update the internal state every time, but that seems very round about for something I'm hoping teloxide already has built in?

Is there any way I can have multiple users mutating the same internal state of the bot?

Here's the code:

Here's the code I'm using. This is lightly adjusted from the [`db_remember.rs`](https://github.com/teloxide/teloxide/blob/master/crates/teloxide/examples/db_remember.rs) example so that I can get a number, reset the number, and set a number to something new using `\set XXX`

`src/main.rs`:

```rs
use teloxide::{
    dispatching::dialogue::{
        serializer::Bincode,
        ErasedStorage, RedisStorage, Storage,
    },
    prelude::*,
    utils::command::BotCommands,
};
use serde::{self, Deserialize, Serialize};

type MyDialogue = Dialogue<State, ErasedStorage<State>>;
type MyStorage = std::sync::Arc<ErasedStorage<State>>;
type HandlerResult = Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;

#[derive(Clone, Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum State {
    #[default]
    Start,
    GotNumber(i32),
}

#[derive(Clone, BotCommands)]
#[command(rename_rule = "lowercase", description = "These commands are supported:")]
pub enum Command {
    #[command(description = "set your number.")]
    Set { num: i32 },
    #[command(description = "get your number.")]
    Get,
    #[command(description = "reset your number.")]
    Reset,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    pretty_env_logger::init();
    log::info!("Starting DB remember bot...");

    let bot = Bot::from_env();

    let storage: MyStorage = RedisStorage::open("redis://127.0.0.1:6379", Bincode).await.unwrap().erase();

    let handler = Update::filter_message()
        .enter_dialogue::<Message, ErasedStorage<State>, State>()
        .branch(dptree::case![State::Start].endpoint(start))
        .branch(
            dptree::case![State::GotNumber(n)]
                .branch(dptree::entry().filter_command::<Command>().endpoint(got_number))
                .branch(dptree::endpoint(invalid_command)),
        );

    Dispatcher::builder(bot, handler)
        .dependencies(dptree::deps![storage])
        .enable_ctrlc_handler()
        .build()
        .dispatch()
        .await;
}

async fn start(bot: Bot, dialogue: MyDialogue, msg: Message) -> HandlerResult {
    match msg.text().map(|text| text.parse::<i32>()) {
        Some(Ok(n)) => {
            log::info!("[{:?}] Number set to {n}", msg.chat.username());
            dialogue.update(State::GotNumber(n)).await?;
            bot.send_message(
                msg.chat.id,
                format!("Remembered number {n}. Now use /get or /reset."),
            )
            .await?;
        }
        _ => {
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "Please, send me a number.").await?;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

async fn got_number(
    bot: Bot,
    dialogue: MyDialogue,
    num: i32, // Available from `State::GotNumber`.
    msg: Message,
    cmd: Command,
) -> HandlerResult {
    let old_num = num;
    match cmd {
        Command::Set { num } => {
            log::info!("[{:?}] Number changed from {} to {}",  msg.chat.username(), old_num, num);
            dialogue.update(State::GotNumber(num)).await?;
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, format!("Set your number from {} to {}", old_num, num)).await?;
        }
        Command::Get => {
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, format!("Here is your number: {num}.")).await?;
        }
        Command::Reset => {
            dialogue.reset().await?;
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "Number reset.").await?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

async fn invalid_command(bot: Bot, msg: Message) -> HandlerResult {
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "Please, send /get or /reset.").await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
teloxide = { version = "0.12", features = ["macros", "redis-storage", "bincode-serializer"] }
log = "0.4"
pretty_env_logger = "0.4"
tokio = { version =  "1.8", features = ["rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
serde_yaml = "0.9.17"
serde = "1.0.152"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered by [WaffleLapkin](https://github.com/WaffleLapkin) on the [Teloxide github discussion page](https://github.com/teloxide/teloxide/discussions/838#discussioncomment-4869660):

> The dialogue storages in teloxide store state per chat, if you need something else, you'll need to work with databases directly.

So I ended up using a Redis database to store the game state, and regular in-memory for storing teloxide's state. Something like:

```rs
// Cargo.toml: redis = { version = "*" }
extern crate redis;
use redis::{Commands, Connection};

/// Establish a connection to the redis database, 
/// used for sharing Game state across
/// different instances of the bot
fn connect_to_redis() -> Result<Connection, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Sync + Send>> {
    let client = redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/")?;
    let conn = client.get_connection()?;
    // Cargo.toml: log = "0.4"
    log::info!("Redis connection established");
    Ok(conn)
}
```

But then you also can't directly store a rust struct into redis, so I used `serde_yaml` to serialise the game state:

```rs
fn set_game_state(
    conn: &mut Connection,
    game: Game,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let game_key = "game_state";
    conn.set::<&str, String, ()>(game_key, serde_yaml::to_string(&game)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

And then stored it all as one long string in a single key in the DB.

To retrieve the game state is a similar operation, but I also added in some logic to create the game from an existing "template" YAML file `game.yaml` if the key doesn't exist:

```rs
fn get_game_state(conn: &mut Connection) -> Result<Game, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let game_state_key = "game_state";
    let game_state: Game = if conn.exists(game_state_key)? {
        log::debug!("Getting game state");
        conn.get::<&str, String>(game_state_key)
            .and_then(|game_state| Ok(serde_yaml::from_str::<Game>(&game_state).unwrap().into()))?
    } else {
        log::debug!("Creating game state");
        let s = Game::new("challenges.yaml")?;
        let serialised = serde_yaml::to_string(&s)?;
        conn.set::<&str, String, ()>(game_state_key, serialised)?;
        s
    };
    Ok(game_state)
}
```

A bit overkill, but it works.